# How to weight an array with another array of same length without disturbing the order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to python and I need to reweigh an array by another array of the same length without disturbing the order, like I want to weigh component by component.

I was trying using NumPy like

```py
J1_wt = np.histogram(F2, bins = 30, weights = weigh_Clust)
```

but this will definitely change the order.

My data is like this:

```
F1=[1.72288135,1.80961059,1.86767127,1.9610155,,2.02323446,2.07557286
,2.17004116,2.22494428,2.29753376,2.3668508,,2.42850874,2.51389674
,2.58029821,2.64361637,2.71345954,2.7655551,,2.82787335,2.8861585
,2.93373297,2.98516628,3.0189053,,3.05360633,3.08751637,3.09396867
,3.08311305,2.98948089,2.80641976,2.55476307,2.36904108,2.10458288]
weigh_Clust = [1.9980e-01,3.5495e-01,5.3415e-01,7.3330e-01,8.7739e-01,1.0000e+00
,8.6047e-01,7.2936e-01,6.0223e-01,5.8059e-01,4.5522e-01,3.3358e-01
,3.2457e-01,2.4599e-01,1.9208e-01,1.8167e-01,1.4581e-01,1.0866e-01
,1.0211e-01,9.1641e-02,5.9966e-02,5.7601e-02,3.7803e-02,2.3540e-02
,2.0282e-02,4.2473e-03,2.8461e-03,2.2244e-03,8.3204e-04,1.9426e-04]
```

Maybe simple multiplication is enough, but I am not sure about that.

Can someone please help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Look at [numpy.dot()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not clear, what you mean with "to reweigh an array by another array ". But if it is an elementwise multiplication then you might do

```
import numpy as np

F1 = np.array(F1)
wC = np.array(weigh_Clust)

F_W = F1*wC
```

If you need the scalar (=inner) product then:

```
np.dot(F1*wC)
```

A weighted mean is:

```
np.dot(F1*wC)/np.sum(wC)
```

After all, this might be what you are interested in:

```
def plot():
    x = np.arange(F1.shape[0])
    with plt.style.context('fivethirtyeight'): 
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22,11)) 
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax1.plot(x,F1,label='F1')
        ax1.plot(x,F1*wC,label='F1*wC')
        ax1.fill_between(x,F1, F1*wC, color='teal', alpha=0.2)
        plt.title('Weighted (F1*wC) against unweighted (F1)', fontweight='bold')
        plt.legend();plt.savefig('F1.png');plt.show()

plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response,   I know That simple multiplication.

Comment: I want to see how the first array 'F1' will change if I give weight to each element that is given in the array 'weight_Clust ' Or simply If you can explain how I can give weight to every element of an array

Comment: the question is: "how I can give weight to every element of an array" FOR DOING WHAT? E.g. the weighted mean (see my edited answer) ? What's the operation after weighting? Or: what is the application (a practical example)?

Comment: Weighted mean will give me a number but I want an array of the same length as F1, I want to plot the array F1 and the weighted array let say F1_w (which I want to get after giving weight to each element of array F1 which I do not know) against an array let say E = np.logspace(9, 15, 31). If I simply plot F1 and E like plt.plot(E, F1), it means the weight of each element is 1, right? So, I want to see the difference if I plot the weighted (F1_W) and unweighted F1 array against E. I hope it will explain better what I want thanks.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response, it is really helpful.

Comment: I have another question related to the same issue, please help me, thanks. The question is I am binning randomly distributed data from a txt file using a function f, binEdges = np.histogram(data,  bins = bins, weights = freq)

Comment: Here 'f' will give the sum of weight in each bin, right? but I need to change the weight with respect to each bin, like my bins range is 1 - 10, what I want to do is the following: for the first bin I want to multiply all the weights in the txt file with the same number and for the second bin I also want to multiply the weights with another number and so on for all the bins. after changing the weights then I want to perform the operation 'f, binEdges = np.histogram(data,  bins = bins, weights = freq)'.

Comment: since you are new at stackoverflow: (1.) if an answer gives you a good idea, give an upvote (= upward button to the left), (2) if an answer is a solution for you, give a "solved" (= check sign below the downward button to the left), (3) open new post for a new question.